Как копировать код в редактор Free Pascal IDE?
Есть у меня вот этот FreePascal:

И я в нём периодически пишу программы.
И вот такая проблема - некоторые коды я беру с других источников, чтобы потестить, а они довольно длинные, например:
{Программа ASCII_TABLE выводит на экран таблицу ASCII символов}

program ASCII_TABLE;

uses CRT;

var i : byte;
j : byte;
ch : byte;
st : string;

begin
   GoToXY(2, 2);
   Write('Код Симв. Код Симв. Код Симв. Код Симв. ');
   Write('Код Симв. Код Симв. Код Симв. Код Симв. ');
   for j := 0 to 7 do
   for i := 0 to 15 do
      begin
         GoToXY(j*10+2, i+4);
         ch := i+(j*16);
         if ch < 10 then st := ' '
         else if ch < 100 then st := ' '
         else st := ' ';
         Write(ch, st, Chr(ch));
      end;
   GoToXY(2, 22);
   Write('Чтобы посмотреть следующую страницу, нажмите ENTER');
   Readln;
   ClrScr;
   GoToXY(2, 2);
   Write('Код Симв. Код Симв. Код Симв. Код Симв. ');
   Write('Код Симв. Код Симв. Код Симв. Код Симв. ');
   for j := 0 to 7 do
   for i := 0 to 15 do
      begin
         GoToXY(j*10+2, i+4);
         ch := i+(j*16) + 128;
         if ch < 10 then st := ' '
         else if ch < 100 then st := ' '
         else st := ' ';
         Write(ch, st, Chr(ch));
      end;
   GoToXY(2, 22);
   Write('Нажмите ENTER для выхода из программы');
   Readln;
end.

И вот перепечатывать весь код очень нудно и долго, а копировать в редактор не получается почему-то.
С макросами не дружу, а если сохранить файл исходника через другую программу, то в самом редакторе она неправильно декодируется.
Выглядит это так:
Код из примера в Notepad++

Этот же код в Pascal:


И вот ищу как всё-таки вставить в Паскаль код, скопированный из другого места.
Если кто-то знает, может это редактор некорректно работает?

"если сохранить файл исходника через другую программу, то в самом редакторе она неправильно декодируется" - выяснить почему и поправить было бы правильным решением.

А что происходит -то?

В этой оболочке вы можете выбрать кодировку текста? (866 и т.д.)

@MBo, наверное могу, как-то не видно этих настроек, похоже нет

Набрал программу в Word. Скопировал, вставил "Paste from Windows" - кракозябры.
Перед копированием в Word включил русскую раскладку клавиатуры. Теперь вставилось нормально. В буфере Windows включается информация о кодовой странице.
То же самое, если с этой страницы копировать:
program a;
begin
  writeln('Привет');
  readln;
end.


Cовет из кода помог исправить глюки в коде, я везде поменял write на writeln, как в примере, и все глюки которые были с программами ранее, исчезли после замены write на writeln

writeln отличается тем, что переводит курсор на новую строку, так что странно, что такая замена повлияла.

Вот тут нашёл:

Только кодировка такая же баговая(

Ну я написал, что мне помогло.

@MBo, это я в англ раскладке, так что спасибо, помогло
